# Setting Tmux prefix

Tags: tmux

I am trying to set the Tmux prefix as `Space+Space` key because `CTRL+a` and `CTRL+Space` is used by other applications in my computer.

I tried `set -g prefix Space-Space`. That didnt work which is believe is because this only works with `C-<any key>` or `M-<any key>`.

I even tried binding keys but `bind-key` only allows one key to be bound to a command.

Any idea on how I can set `Space + Space` as the prefix key?